# alternative to listagg in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar, clob

listagg is a function introduced in Oracle 11.2! now this function is bugging us allot, we are migrating from MySQL to Oracle and we have this query:

```
SELECT
    p_id,
    MAX(registered) AS registered,
    listagg(MESSAGE, ' ') within GROUP (ORDER BY registered) AS MESSAGE
  FROM
    umm_parent_id_remarks_v m
  GROUP BY
    m.p_id;
```

is works fine in MySQL as far as we know
what bugging us is under Oracle it returns VARCAR and not CLOB as we need!
**the text is huge and we do need it to be CLOB**!

here is what I tried to do!

create a CLOB_T table of CLOB Type!

then create the function

```
create or replace
function listaggclob (t in clob_t) 
  return clob
as 
  ret clob := '';
  i   number;
begin
  i := t.first;
  while i is not null loop
    if ret is not null then
      ret := ret || ' ';
    end if;
    ret := ret || t(i);
    i := t.next(i);
  end loop;
  return ret;
end;
```

now if I run it:

```
  SELECT
        p_id,
        MAX(registered) AS registered,
        listaggclob(cast(collect (MESSAGE) as clob_t)) MESSAGE
      FROM
        umm_parent_id_remarks_v m
      GROUP BY
        m.p_id;
```

I get

**ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type**

is there any solution for it?

thanks you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [collect](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306) or [write your own aggregation function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php).

Comment: I did write my own function and I updated my question, please review my question again, thanks

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that error - it's probably worth posting it as a new question though, you will get more people looking at it that way.

Answer (score 5):

Use xmlAgg, example is shown below:

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,colname,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY colname).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST
FROM tablename;
```

This will return clob value and so no need to create custom function.

Comment: XMLAGG is very slow.

Comment: Is there any fast alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [user-defined aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm).

Differnt string aggregation techniques are shown [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php). They include an example for user-defined aggregate functions.

Comment: Good set of options there. Is there any info on which are faster?

Comment: I don't have any info about performance. I guess it mainly depends on the overall execution plan and how they fit into that execution plan. So it might differ from query to query.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the `ORA-22814` error by using `MULTISET` instead of `COLLECT`:

```
SELECT
    p_id,
    MAX(registered) AS registered,
    listaggclob(cast(multiset(
        select MESSAGE
        from umm_parent_id_remarks_v
        where umm_parent_id_remarks_v.p_id = m.p_id
    ) as clob_t)) MESSAGE
  FROM
    umm_parent_id_remarks_v m
  GROUP BY
    m.p_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

WM_CONCAT worked for me.

```
SELECT replace(WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(myTable.name), ',', ';')
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myTable.id
```

I wrapped it with a "replace" to specify a different item separator (';') from the one used by WM_CONCAT (',').

Comment: Note that WM_CONCAT is not available in 12c, Express Edition, and any database where Workspace Manager is not installed.

Comment: it is not supported nor documented nowadays

Answer (score 1):

```sql
-- Creating Clobe Type --
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "MSCONCATIMPL_CLOB" AS OBJECT (
    resultstring   CLOB,
    delimiter      VARCHAR2(10),

    STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize ( io_srccontext IN OUT msconcatimpl_clob ) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
        self IN OUT msconcatimpl_clob,
        value   IN CLOB
    ) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
        self            IN msconcatimpl_clob,
        o_returnvalue   OUT CLOB,
        i_flags         IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
        self IN OUT msconcatimpl_clob,
        i_ctx2   IN msconcatimpl_clob
    ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/
-- Creating Clobe Type Body --

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY "MSCONCATIMPL_CLOB" IS
    STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize ( io_srccontext IN OUT msconcatimpl_clob ) RETURN NUMBER
        IS
    BEGIN
        io_srccontext := msconcatimpl_clob(
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        io_srccontext.delimiter := ' ';
        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END odciaggregateinitialize;

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
        self IN OUT msconcatimpl_clob,
        value   IN CLOB
    ) RETURN NUMBER
        IS
    BEGIN
        IF
            value IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            IF
                self.resultstring IS NULL
            THEN
                self.resultstring := self.resultstring || value;
            ELSE
                self.resultstring := self.resultstring
                 || self.delimiter
                 || value;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END odciaggregateiterate;

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
        self            IN msconcatimpl_clob,
        o_returnvalue   OUT CLOB,
        i_flags         IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER
        IS
    BEGIN
        o_returnvalue := self.resultstring;
        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END odciaggregateterminate;

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
        self IN OUT msconcatimpl_clob,
        i_ctx2   IN msconcatimpl_clob
    ) RETURN NUMBER
        IS
    BEGIN
        IF
                self.resultstring IS NULL
            AND
                i_ctx2.resultstring IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            self.resultstring := i_ctx2.resultstring;
        ELSIF
            self.resultstring IS NOT NULL
        AND
            i_ctx2.resultstring IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            self.resultstring := self.resultstring
             || self.delimiter
             || i_ctx2.resultstring;
        END IF;

        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END odciaggregatemerge;

END;
/

-- Creating Clobe Function --

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ms_concat_clob ( input   VARCHAR2 ) RETURN CLOB
    PARALLEL_ENABLE
AGGREGATE USING msconcatimpl_clob;
/
```