# oracle pl/sql results into one string

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a simple stored procedure that stores queried result into one string.

```
v_string1 varchar2(100);

Select column1
From dual;
```

Will return

```
column 1
--------
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

I want to store "aaaa, bbbb, cccc' into v_string1.
And all I can think of is a Cursor...
Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternative to listagg in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412512/alternative-to-listagg-in-oracle)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9092/7):

```
select LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) AS names
from temp_table
```

Comment: Coolio...I've never seen that function before +1!

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't either until I googled it. Glad it helped and it caused me to learn something new too :D

Answer (score 1):

Another option using pure SQL that will work before Oracle 11G, although is still limited to 4000 characters for the string.

```
Select ltrim(max(names), ', ') as names
From (
  Select sys_connect_by_path(name, ' ,') as names
  From (
    Select name, row_number() over (order by name) as rown
    From temp_table
  )
  Start with rown = 1
  Connect by rown = prior rown + 1
)
```