# concat result of sql query using field seperator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query:

```
SELECT *  FROM (SELECT col1,col2,col3,ROWNUM R 
                FROM TBL WHERE  ROWNUM < 3) 
          WHERE R='2';
```

(rownum will change each time giving only one record at a time )

```
column1      column2       column3
alpha         beta          gamma
```

I need result as:

```
alpha,beta,gamma
```

All i need to do is, field separators in between the output.

This is not relevant to the suggested link below and not a duplicate!

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954511/oracle-pl-sql-results-into-one-string)

Comment: but I think LISTAGG is returning results of single column and this question has seperate columns

Comment: No, this is not the duplicate to the LISTAGG topic. OP is asking for **string concatenation** and not **string aggregation**. I am reopening it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: the OP marked it as duplicate themselves though...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That's strange, because OP marked my answer as answered, and then accepted the topic to be a duplicate of a completely different topic. I see why robo-user marked it as duplicate.

Comment: Is it possible to change it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

**CONCAT** function

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT concat(concat(concat(concat('a', ','), col2), ','), col3),
    ROWNUM R
  FROM TBL
  WHERE ROWNUM < 3
  )
WHERE R=2;
```

`||` concatenation operator

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT col1||','||col2||','||col3,ROWNUM R FROM TBL WHERE ROWNUM < 3
  )
WHERE R=2;
```

Another thing, no need to use single quotes around the value for **ROWNUM**, it unnecessarily converts it into **string**, just leave it as **NUMBER**.

Answer (score 3):

If `LISTAGG` is not what you are looking for then, `DUMMYCOL` may help.--

```
   SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT col1,
    ','AS DUMMYCOL,
    col2,
    ','AS DUMMYCOL,
    col3,
    ROWNUM R
  FROM TBL
  WHERE ROWNUM < 3
  )
WHERE R='2';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following:-

```
SELECT *  
FROM (SELECT col1||','||col2||','||col3,ROWNUM R 
      FROM TBL WHERE  ROWNUM < 3) 
WHERE R='2';
```