# Concatenate rows into CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

There are many similar questions on this subject, but I can't find any with solutions that keep into account anything with an end result too large for varchar2.

So what I'm trying to do is change this:

```
Column1 | Column2
-------- --------
1         Hello
1         world,
1         please help
2         Thanks
2         world,
2         you're the best.
```

Into this:

```
Column1 | Column2
-------- --------
1         Hello world, please help
2         Thanks world, you're the best.
```

My particular problem is that there are a few cases where the new concatenated value exceeds 4000 characters, so I can't use `LISTAGG` as I hoped to. I'm particularly interested in solutions without having to write a function, but either will do.

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412512/alternative-to-listagg-in-oracle ?

Comment: The results of LISTAGG are constrained to the maximum size of VARCHAR2 in SQL (i.e. 4000).  For larger strings we would need to use an alternative means of gathering the elements (such as a collection or a user-defined PL/SQL function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Column1 , LISTAGG(Column2, ' ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Column2) AS employees
FROM   Table1
GROUP BY Column1 ;
```

**[Please have a look at this Article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)**

Answer (score 3):

As de.hh.holger already pointed out, the [LISTAGG WITH CLOB? STRING AGGREGATION EXCEEDING 4000 CHARACTERS WITH XMLAGG](http://sonra.io/listagg-with-clob-string-aggregation-exceeding-4000-characters-with-xmlagg/) does indeed solve this issue.

I have elaborated a little further on the subject and this should do the trick in case of a really long string message:

```
SELECT
   table_row_id,
   DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
     EXTRACT(
       xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?><document>' ||
               XMLAGG(
                 XMLTYPE('<V>' || DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(data_value)|| '</V>')
                 order by myOrder).getclobval() || '</document>'),
               '/document/V/text()').getclobval(),1) AS data_value
FROM (
   SELECT 1 myOrder, 1 table_row_id,'abcdefg>' data_value FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 1 table_row_id,'hijklmn' data_value FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3, 1 table_row_id,'opqrst' data_value FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 1 table_row_id,'uvwxyz' data_value FROM dual)
GROUP BY
   table_row_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmlagg to concate clob column  values below is the query its working on the above table:-

```
SELECT DEMO.COLUMN1, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, DEMO.COLUMN2, '').EXTRACT('//TEXT()') ORDER BY DEMO.COLUMN1).GETCLOBVAL(),',') AS COLUMN2
FROM DEMO_TBL DEMO
GROUP BY COLUMN1;
```