# Aggregating / Concatenation of very long Varchar2 strings and find key words in the text || Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, aggregate

I have been given a task to develop a script/ function/ query to aggregate groups of rows in a table and then search for specific keywords in it. The column to be aggregated is a varchar2 column with size 3200 and some of the aggregated rows have lengths way beyond 5000.

(I understand that the size of varchar2 is 4000)

When I try to aggregate the data into a single column, it gives a "result of string concatenation is too long" error (ORA-01489)

I have tried inbuilt aggregators like LISTAGG, XMLAGG, and also some custom functions but I have been asked to prefer a SQL query over a function or procedure.

Once I can get the data to be aggregated, I have to then search through the rows for matching keywords.
(can't just search the rows without aggregating as some of the words are split across the rows, eg row1 ends with "KEYW" and row2 starts with "ORD" if I need to look for "KEYWORD" in the table

my table kind of looks like this (can't post the real table data, sorry),

```
id_1 | id_2 | name | row_num | description 
 1       5      A     0         this has so
 1       5      A     1         me keyword
 1       5      B     0         this is
 1       3      E     0         new some
 2       12     A     0         diff str
```

here the unique rows are identified using the first 3 columns and the 4th column lists the order in which these "description" strings need to be concatenated.

I would like to get the output as:

```
id_1 | id_2 | name | description (concated)
  1      5     A      this is **some** keyword
  1      3     E      new **some**
```

when looking for the keyword "some"

Please help as I am fairly new to DBs and any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Kunal

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040761/concatenate-rows-into-clob - you seem to say you've "tried XMLAGG" which is what it advocates, so you should post your failed attempt into the question

Comment: @CaiusJard, I have gone through that page and I have tried that solution, it works in normal cases but fails when the final concatenated size exceeds 4000, I am looking for help to hold a long (very long) string in either a column or variable to then search through it for a keyword.

even a PLSQL block that can do this task iteratively will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You tried the accepted solution, not the most upvoted one I think. Don't be misled into thinking the green tick means "the right answer" or "the one that will work for you", it merely means "the answer the OP chose to implement" - read all the answers and their surrounding commentary - there is an answer there that specifically talks about LISTAGG (what the accepted answer uses) not working for large strings, and uses XMLAGG instead. If you tried something that should have worked according to another answer, but didn't *add it to your question* like "i tried X fromY like Z but it gave error E"