# Return values of select in function/procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, view, plsql

I have a SQL sentence where I make a minus of two tables to search the differences. As I use frequently I would like to create a function or procedure to make these and get output by screen. Someone could explain me how is the best way to make these, could you put me some example?

Comment: Is there a reason for not putting this query into a [view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the what you're looking for, if you're using Oracle 11g Release 2:

```
create or replace procedure prnt_my_view(my_view in varchar2, separator in varchar2 default ',') is
    type myrefcur is ref cursor;
    type rowtext is table of varchar2(256);
    rowdef varchar2(256);
    rows_cv myrefcur;
    text rowtext;
begin
    select listagg(column_name,'||'''||separator||'''||')  within group (order by column_id) into rowdef from user_tab_columns where lower(table_name) = lower(my_view);
    open rows_cv for 'select '||rowdef||' from '||my_view;
    fetch rows_cv bulk collect into text;
    for i in text.first..text.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(text(i));
    end loop;
    close rows_cv;
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('something is wrong:'||sqlerrm);
end;
```

edit:
if you can't use listagg, check other solutions for example here: [alternative to listagg in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412512/alternative-to-listagg-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

If you **frequently** use the **MINUS query**, then it is better to create a **view** on the query. To fetch the resultset, you just need to select from the view.

For example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
   SELECT column_list FROM table1
     MINUS
   SELECT column_list FROM table2
```

And to fetch the result,

```
SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

Read the documentation for more details on [CREATE VIEW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use views for the minus sql statement But I would like to create a function or procedure to can see these outputs with dbms_output. Cold you suggest me how could I do these? Thanks

Comment: @user104906 If you really want to do it in PL/SQL, then simply use `OPEN CURSOR FOR your_query` and return a ref cursor. For example, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27812983/3989608