# LISTAGG function: “result of string concatenation is too long”

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, clob, listagg

> [Error] Execution (1: 21): ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Getting ORA-01489 when executing the below query as the string is longer than 4000 bytes, can someone help on how to replace the listagg with clob or an alternative for the issue.

```sql
    SELECT '{'||dbms_xmlgen.convert(rtrim(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,examp,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY examp).GetClobVal(),','),1)||'}' 
    AS LIST FROM (select '"'||state||'":'||'{'||**listagg**('"'||CODE||'":"'||DISPLAYNAME ||'"',',') 
    within group(order by DISPLAYNAME)||'}' as examp from (select distinct ea.STATE,ea.CODE,ea.DISPLAYNAME from VIEW ea,
    REGION rea where REGIONID='?' AND ea.CODE= rea.CODE and nvl(rea.inactivedate,sysdate+2)>sysdate) 
    ex group by state)
```

Comment: You're already using the xmlagg approach for other parts of your query; so can't you change the listagg to to the same?

Comment: I tried changing , but that is throwing me ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [alternative to listagg in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412512/alternative-to-listagg-in-oracle)